# Show directly from the definition that the sequence $x_n =1+\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + ...+ \frac{1}{n^2} $ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I saw an example online where it was a factorial in the denominator instead of an exponent. It went like this.

prove that $\frac{1}{n!} < \frac{1}{2n}$ as long as $n\geq 4$. Then, by using induction on $m$, prove that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n+m} \leq \frac{1}{2n−1}
\end{equation}

Now if  $x > 0$ is given, choose $N$ so that if $n > N$ then $\frac{1}{2n} < x$ . Then if $n > m > N$, we have
\begin{align}
  \left|1+\frac{1}{2!}+ ... +\frac{1}{n!}−
    \left(1+\frac{1}{2!}+ ... +\frac{1}{m!}\right)\right| & =
  \left|\frac{1}{(m +1)!}+ ... +\frac{1}{(m + n)!}\right|\leq \\ 
  \left|\frac{1}{2m+1} + ... +\frac{1}{2m+n}\right| \frac{1}{2m} &\leq x
\end{align}
so the sequence is Cauchy.

Would my question follow along this?

Comment: See [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick guide on how to format math on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

$$\mid x_n-x_m \mid = \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \int_m^n \frac{1}{x^2} \; dx = \frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{m}.$$

If $\epsilon$ is given, chose $N$ greater than $1/\epsilon$.